# collapse data frame with embedded matrices

Tags: r, dataframe

Under certain conditions, R generates data frames that contain matrices as elements. This requires some determination to do by hand, but happens e.g. with the results of an `aggregate()` call where the aggregation function returns multiple values:

```
set.seed(101)
d0 <- data.frame(g=factor(rep(1:2,each=20)), x=rnorm(20))
d1 <- aggregate(x~g, data=d0, FUN=function(x) c(m=mean(x), s=sd(x)))
str(d1)
## 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ g: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 2
##  $ x: num [1:2, 1:2] -0.0973 -0.0973 0.8668 0.8668
##   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
##   .. ..$ : NULL
##  .. ..$ : chr  "m" "s"
```

This makes a certain amount of sense, but can make trouble for downstream processing code (for example, `ggplot2` doesn't like it). The printed representation can also be confusing if you don't know what you're looking at:

```
d1
##   g         x.m         x.s
## 1 1 -0.09731741  0.86678436
## 2 2 -0.09731741  0.86678436
```

I'm looking for a relatively simple way to collapse this object to a regular three-column data frame (either with names `g`, `m`, `s`, *or* with names `g`, `x.m`, `x.s` ...).

I know this problem won't arise with tidyverse (`group_by` + `summarise`), but am looking for a base-R solution.